How to make libcurl work with other web connected libraries
I have a c++ libcurl sending emails while TWS API is running. TWS API connects on port 4002. Periodically I send an email with libcurl and it holds the contens of some of the data sent from TWS API. I’m not sure what’s causing the overlap. This is my first time using libcurl.

string sender = "senderEmail@gmail.com";
string password = "password!";
string receiver1 = "otheremail@gmail.com";
string receiver2 = "5551234567@msg.fi.google.com";

string latestEmailSubject = "default Subject";
string latestEmailBody = "email Body";

size_t writeCallback(void* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp) {
    // Simply discard the response for simplicity in this example
    return size * nmemb;
}
struct upload_status {
    int lines_read;
};
static size_t payload_source(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp)
{
    struct upload_status* upload_ctx = (struct upload_status*)userp;
    const char* data;

    if ((size == 0) || (nmemb == 0) || ((size * nmemb) < 1)) {
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "sending" << endl;

    string senderLine = ("From: " + sender + "\r\n");
    string receiverLine = "To: " + receiver1 + "\r\n";
    string ccLine = "Cc: " + receiver2 + "\r\n";

    string subjectLine = "Subject: " + latestEmailSubject + "\r\n";
    string bodyLine = latestEmailBody + "\r\n";
    string footerLine = "Sent from Accelerated Investing at " + StockThread::TimeToString(system_clock::now()) + "\r\n";

    static const char* payload_text[] = {
  "Date: Mon, 29 Nov 2023 21:54:29 +1100\r\n",
    receiverLine.c_str(),
    senderLine.c_str(),
    ccLine.c_str(),
    "Message-ID: <dcd7cb36-11db-487a-9f3a-e652a9458efd@"
    "rfcpedant.example.org>\r\n",
    subjectLine.c_str(),
    "\r\n", 
    bodyLine.c_str(),
    "\r\n",
    footerLine.c_str(),
    //"Check RFC5322.\r\n",
    NULL
    };

    data = payload_text[upload_ctx->lines_read];

    if (data) {
        size_t len = strlen(data);
        memcpy(ptr, data, len);
        upload_ctx->lines_read++;

        return len;
    }

    cout << "end of payload_source()" << endl;


    return 0;
}


void Strategy::SendEmail(string subject, string message)
{
    //Solution 1 from here: https://www.codeease.net/programming/c%2b%2b/how-to-send-email-in-c++-program
    //followup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54778300/using-libcurl-to-send-an-email-in-c

    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    
    struct upload_status upload_ctx;

    upload_ctx.lines_read = 0;

    if (curl) 
    {
        latestEmailSubject = subject;
        latestEmailBody = message;

        // Set the SMTP server details

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "senderEmail@gmail.com");
        

        //generated password copied from gmail
        //go here to change them: https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/apppasswords?pli=1&rapt=AEjHL4M_GxOrC43lsW14JrCVFuwH5SuOBPthkSLYpA090srtteYJgTSiaN4WsvReFBGlCQKQJFRGZbGYhPOQ02dt0qBMD-T6WX-QBmcb6BqqpVRVhXWJyCc
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "1234 5678 90ab cdef");

        // Set the sender's email address
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM, sender);
        // Set the recipient's email address
        struct curl_slist* recipients = NULL;
        recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, receiver1.c_str());
        recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, receiver2.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT, recipients);
        // Set the email subject
        
        // Set the email body
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, payload_source);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, &upload_ctx);
        // Set the callback function to handle the server response
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writeCallback);

        cout << "sending:" << endl;
        cout << "sending subject:" << subject << endl;
        cout << "sending body:" << message << endl;
        // Perform the email sending operation
        CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        // Check for errors
        if (res != CURLE_OK) 
        {
            std::cerr << "curl_easy_perform() failed: " << curl_easy_strerror(res) << std::endl;
        }
        // Cleanup
        curl_slist_free_all(recipients);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

        cout << "end of SendEmail()" << endl;
    }

}

The setup for TWS API is here:
const char* host = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "";
int port = argc > 2 ? atoi(argv[2]) : 0;
if (port <= 0)
    port = 4002;
string connectOptions = "";
int clientId = 0;

unsigned attempt = 0;

for (;;) {

    Strategy client;
    EClientSocket* socketpointer = client.m_pClient;

    client.runningLiveTest = testOnlineOrders || exportingOnlineData;       

    if (!client.isConnected())
    {
        client.connect(host, port, clientId);
    }
    …

It also seems to send some string in a vector about to be sent to spdlog.

Looks like you're storing a bunch of pointers to string data in payload_text. Those strings go out of scope at the end of the function and you're left with dangling pointers to wherever. That memory being reused for something else is certainly possible.

Ok. Thank you. That sounds like what's happening. So would I just need to declare senderLine, receiverLine , and the other strings there being cast as c_str() as member variables?

If you have to send the data line by line then I'd add a vector of string to upload_status,
construct the data in SendEmail, and the only responsibility of payload_source is the copy the current line over.

The next issue you may run into is not paying any attention to the maximum amount of data curl is prepared to handle. Since your code looks a lot like the example at https://curl.se/libcurl/c/smtp-mail.html you might want to take a second look about how they handle that.

Yeah it looks close to what I used. ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54778300/using-libcurl-to-send-an-email-in-c ) Is the issue related to the size of the message or the frequency of the messages?

The issue was caused by dangling pointers in payload_source(). Thanks to @Retired_Ninja for the tip. A cleaner way to do this is this:
string sender = "senderEmail@gmail.com";
string password = "password!";
string receiver1 = "otheremail@gmail.com";
string receiver2 = "5551234567@msg.fi.google.com";

size_t writeCallback(void* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp) {
    // Simply discard the response for simplicity in this example
    return size * nmemb;
}
struct upload_status {
    int lines_read;
    size_t bytes_read;
    vector<string> emailLines;
};

static size_t payload_source(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp)
{
    struct upload_status* upload_ctx = (struct upload_status*)userp;
    const char* data;
    size_t room = size * nmemb;    

    if ((size == 0) || (nmemb == 0) || ((size * nmemb) < 1)) {
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "sending" << endl;
    data = upload_ctx->emailLines[upload_ctx->lines_read].c_str();

    if (data && upload_ctx->lines_read < upload_ctx->emailLines.size())    {
        size_t len = strlen(data);
        if (room < len)
            len = room;
        memcpy(ptr, data, len);
        upload_ctx->lines_read++;
        upload_ctx->bytes_read += len;

        return len;
    }

    cout << "end of payload_source()" << endl;


    return 0;
}


void Strategy::SendEmail(string subject, string message)
{
    //Solution 1 from here: https://www.codeease.net/programming/c%2b%2b/how-to-send-email-in-c++-program
    //followup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54778300/using-libcurl-to-send-an-email-in-c

    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    
    struct upload_status upload_ctx;

    upload_ctx.lines_read = 0;

    if (curl) 
    {
        string senderLine = ("From: " + sender + "\r\n");
        string receiverLine = "To: " + receiver1 + "\r\n";
        string ccLine = "Cc: " + receiver2 + "\r\n";

        string subjectLine = "Subject: " + subject + "\r\n";
        string bodyLine = message + "\r\n";
        string footerLine = "Sent from Accelerated Investing at " +                         StockThread::TimeToString(system_clock::now()) + "\r\n";

        upload_ctx.emailLines = {
            "Date: Mon, 29 Nov 2010 21:54:29 +1100\r\n",
            receiverLine,
            senderLine,
            ccLine,
            "Message-ID: <dcd7cb36-11db-487a-9f3a-e652a9458efd@rfcpedant.example.org>\r\n",
            subjectLine,
            "\r\n",
            bodyLine,
            "\r\n",
            footerLine
            //"Check RFC5322.\r\n",
        };

        // Set the SMTP server details

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "senderEmail@gmail.com");
        

        //generated password copied from gmail
        //go here to change them: https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/apppasswords?pli=1&rapt=AEjHL4M_GxOrC43lsW14JrCVFuwH5SuOBPthkSLYpA090srtteYJgTSiaN4WsvReFBGlCQKQJFRGZbGYhPOQ02dt0qBMD-T6WX-QBmcb6BqqpVRVhXWJyCc
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "1234 5678 90ab cdef");

        // Set the sender's email address
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM, sender);
        // Set the recipient's email address
        struct curl_slist* recipients = NULL;
        recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, receiver1.c_str());
        recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, receiver2.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT, recipients);
        // Set the email subject
        
        // Set the email body
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, payload_source);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, &upload_ctx);
        // Set the callback function to handle the server response
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writeCallback);

        cout << "sending:" << endl;
        cout << "sending subject:" << subject << endl;
        cout << "sending body:" << message << endl;
        // Perform the email sending operation
        CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        // Check for errors
        if (res != CURLE_OK) 
        {
            std::cerr << "curl_easy_perform() failed: " << curl_easy_strerror(res) << std::endl;
        }
        // Cleanup
        curl_slist_free_all(recipients);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

        cout << "end of SendEmail()" << endl;
    }

}

